# Is $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}, L)$ always $0$?

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

Consider an elliptic curve $X$.
The $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{O}_X$ itself is free, so in particular projective.
Thus, $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=0$ for all line bundles $L$ over $X$ by Exercise 2.5.2 in *Weibel: An Introduction to Homological Algebra*.

On the other hand, $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=H^1(\mathcal{O}_X^*, L)$ by the exercise on the bottom of page 1 in these handwritten notes titled *[Extensions of line bundles](https://web.archive.org/web/20220805145214/https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ebullery/math252notes/Section%203_%20Extensions%20of%20line%20bundles.pdf)*.
Now, using $\mathcal{O}_X^*=\mathcal{O}_X$ and applying Serre duality gives:
$$
Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)
=
H^1(\mathcal{O}_X^* \otimes L)
=
H^0(K_X \otimes L^*)^*
=
H^0(L^*)^*.
$$
The term $H^0(L^*)^*$ can be non-zero, namely if $L^*$ has non-negative degree.
This contradicts the first paragraph.

> Question: Which is true? Is $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=0$ for all line bundles $L$ over $X$?

Context for the question:
I'm trying to get an explicit description of an extension of a degree $1$ line bundle by the trivial line bundle over an elliptic curve.
In order to get this explicit description, I'm trying to trace the proof of Theorem 3.4.3 in *Weibel: An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, where it is used that certain $Ext$ groups vanish.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X$ is *not* projective; that would mean the global sections functor is exact which is just not true here. It is also not "free" in the sense that it does not arise from a free-forgetful adjunction.

Comment: I don't know what a free-forgetful adjunction is. My definition of free is being a direct sum of several copies of the ring. But I understand you're saying my definition of free doesn't imply projective in this category.

Comment: Also, I just realised that $\text{Ext}$ and $\mathcal{Ext}$ are two different things. According to Vakil's notation, $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=0$ always, but possibly $\text{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L) \neq 0$. That's Exercise 30.2.C in the November 2017 version of his notes. That's where my confusion originated.

Comment: @user505117 There is not really a rigorous definition of a forgetful functor (rather one heuristically says that it's a functor forgetting some structure) but a free functor is the left adjoint of a forgetful functor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ with an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{G}$ one can show in general (by writing out the definitions) that $$\operatorname{Ext}_X^i(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{G}) \cong H^i(X, \mathcal{G}).$$ See for example **Vakil, #30.2.C**. In particular, this does not need to vanish and you will know many examples where it doesn't vanish.

This also shows that $\mathcal{O}_X$ in general is not projective (despite it being free in the sense of Hartshorne) since otherwise we would have $\operatorname{Ext}^1_X(\mathcal{O}_X, -) = 0$ by the usual homological algebra argument. (A more elementary formulation is as written in Qiaochu Yuan's comment: The global sections functor would be exact.)

So the error here is that (Hartshorne's) freeness does not imply projectivity, as one might be used to from ordinary modules over rings.

Comment: Okay. And as the commenter on the original post pointed out, $\mathcal{O}_X$ is not projective. So, we shouldn't expect $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=0$. That explains the contradiction I presented in my original post.

Comment: I benefitted from reading your answer together with Caution III.6.5.2 in Hartshorne.

Comment: @user505117 I deleted the projectivity part now :p

Comment: If you add an explanation why the argument for $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_X, L)=0$ in my original post is wrong, then I will accept the answer. Such an explanation is contained in Qiaochu Yuan's comment.

Comment: @user505117 Sorry for the late reply, I didn't have much time recently. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Your comment gives many reasons to smile, thanks Georges!

Comment: Hello Qi Zhu: judging from your photograph under your answer you seem to be a very nice, smiling person... (Oh, and by the way the answer is quite good too: +1). In a more mathematical vein the fact that $Hom(\mathcal O_X,-)$ and $\Gamma(X,-)$ are isomorphic functors explains why their derived functors $Ext^i(\mathcal O_X,-)$ and $H^i(X,-)$ are also isomorphic.

Comment: (My comment and Qi Zhu's above got mixed up due to a to a correction of mine. Sorry about that, dear Qi Zhu!)